# How much searches can we do in shodan and after what time the API recharges?

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.6, python-3.7, shodan

I tried Googling about shodan rate limit but couldn't get any good data on how much search can we do and after what time it recharges. Like in GitHub I have 30 requests and after some time it when I finished doing 30 requests it recharges after some time probably in 5 minutes.

```py
>>> s.info()
{'scan_credits': 0, 'usage_limits': {'scan_credits': 0, 'query_credits': 0, 'monitored_ips': 0}, 'plan': 'oss', 'https': False, 'unlocked': False, 'query_credits': 0, 'monitored_ips': 0, 'unlocked_left': 0, 'telnet': False}
>>>
```

The code shows everything is 0 still I can search in shodan, why is that?
I m using python3-shodan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shodan API usage limits reset at the start of every month.

And you're on the Free API tier (`oss` plan) which is why you don't have any query/ scan credits. If you were on a different API plan then you would see how many queries/ scans you're able to perform and how many credits you've already used.

Answer (score 0):

shodan showing you got 100 Query credits per month.